# Parsing xml element to class

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I have xml document (you may look it up [here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s6/sh/d3ac80b9-6177-4943-9563-3cd0e120bddd/85b396cb8b9696a97bbbf9bf02ff059f)) from web request.

I need to get values of ccy, base_ccy, buy and sale attributes from each "exchangerate" element:

```
<exchangerate ccy="EUR" base_ccy="UAH" buy="10.81284" sale="10.81284"/>
```

I've manually created class ExchangeRate, which is looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class ExchangeRate
{
    [XmlAttribute("ccy")]
    public string Ccy
    { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("base_ccy")]
    public string Base_ccy
    { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("buy")]
    public string Buy
    { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("sale")]
    public string Sale
    { get; set; }
}
```

and trying to deserialize xml-element "exchangerate" (which I've isolate from whole xml-document) to the instance of ExchangeRate class in this way:

```
private ExchangeRate DesereilizeXMLNode(XmlNode node)
{
    XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ExchangeRate));
    TextReader reader = new StringReader(node.OuterXml);

    return (ExchangeRate)mySerializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

When I debuging DesereilizeXMLNode method I receiving exception while calling deserialization method. The exception is XAMLParseException in MainWindow.xaml in first line of the Grid element (which is weird) and I think it is not a proper place for calling exception.

The question is: where was I wrong? Am I wrong when tried to create an object instance from xml-element in this way? Maybe I've made mistake when tried to deserialize only xml-element with attributes without deserialization of whole xml-document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify a Serializable for the whole syntax of the XML file for the Deserialize to work! So from the root node in the XML down to this node. (I can't give you an example as your lookup url is not working for me; 501)

---

**EDIT:**

Well then you will have to find the elements and their attributes manually, like the example below. You can't individually Deserialize XmlElements, unless you convert them to an XmlDocument, but that's a bit overdone.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.xml");

XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/account_order/row/exchangerate");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    XmlAttribute ccyAttribute = node.Attributes["ccy"];
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: I've updated the link for xml-response. But my target was not to deserialize whole xml-document, because I don't really need its most part. I need only 3 lines from whole document. So I thought that I might to deserialize only xml-nodes that I need. Is there any other option to create object from single xml-elment with attributes?

Comment: It seems that I can get attribute's values this way. Actually it is not a deserialization, but I guess it's not necessary to use it in my case. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You would have to deserialize the whole document - I think it mightbe easier for you, to find the exchangerate elements you need with xpath. Then write a 'manual deserialiser' that reads the value of each element and populate the properties of an ExchangeRate object.

Comment: Yeah, it'll definitely be easy, because I know how to do it :) But I am curious is there any method to create object from single xml-element with attributes. I want to avoid deserialization of whole xml-document.